# How to Read a boolean flag pass through CLI in vanilla rust

Tags: rust, boolean, command-line-interface

I want to pass boolean flags to a program in rust.  However, I do not want to use any external crates.  How would I do something like that?

Example:

Command: `cargo run -- -t` 
output: `-t flag enabled`

Comment: You have to just use Argv.

Comment: please note the word vanilla in the title.  I dont want to use any libaries.

Comment: I never mentioned any library. Argv is just the way arguments are passed to programs in many languages, C and C++ included.

Comment: Oh, a google search turned up a library named argv, or I miss-read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hand-roll your CLI, you want to use the `std::env` module which has the `args()` function:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-01-accepting-command-line-arguments.html

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    dbg!(args);
}
```

So now all you want to do is whether or not the list of arguments contains `-t` Let me know if you have trouble with that part.

Answer (score 2):

You can roll your own argument parsing by simply consuming [`std::env::args()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/fn.args.html) (skipping the first element) until you run out of elements.  For each element you either alter some state or you signal an error if the argument is unexpected.

Here's a simple example that matches the behavior desired in your question:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Arguments {
    pub test: bool,
}

impl Arguments {
    pub fn parse<S: AsRef<str>>(args: impl IntoIterator<Item=S>) -> Result<Arguments, String> {
        let mut r = Arguments::default();

        for arg in args {
            match arg.as_ref() {
                "-t" => r.test = true,
                x => return Err(format!("Unknown argument: {}", x)),
            }
        }

        Ok(r)
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    let args = Arguments::parse(std::env::args().skip(1))?;

    if args.test {
        println!("-t flag enabled");
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

This basic template can handle a wide variety of use cases.  If using this kind of template, note the following:

- You should use a proper error type instead of `String`.
- You can customize the default state of `Arguments` by removing the `Default` derivation and implementing `Default` yourself.
- It's a bit more work to handle flags that take arguments themselves (like `--foo bar`).  You have to manually loop over a mutable iterator using `Iterator::next()` so that you can pull more elements out of the iterator within the loop.